# c# wpf Click event for header of MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf

I am programmatically creating a context menu

```
MenuItem item;
MenuItem subItem;

_contextmenu.Items.Clear();

item = new MenuItem { Header = "Header Item"};
item.Click += (s, e) => ShowMainWindow();
_contextmenu.Items.Add(item);

subItem = new MenuItem { Header = "Sub Item 1" };
item.Items.Add(subItem);

subItem = new MenuItem { Header = "Sub Item 2" };
item.Items.Add(subItem);
```

The click event is correctly fired for the sub menu items.
How can I get a click event for the header item?

Comment: I suppose you could handle the mouse down event on it. If you cared about doing it right you’d set mouse capture there and do the “click” in mouse up (something like that — Click is more complicated than you think). Why do you want to do this at all? Users don’t expect it. It’s almost always a mistake to get clever like this. Do the normal, expected thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event instead of `Click`:

```
item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => ShowMainWindow();
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` instead and then getting the parent of `e.OriginalSource` to see if it was the header menu item.